# NameError while handling command line arguments

Tags: python

I was trying out a few python test scripts with sqlite3.

Here is the script that I wrote

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
from sys import argv,exit

db_name = "filenames.db"

def define_db():
    try:
        conn = sqlite.connect(db_name)
    except IOError as e:
        print "problem while creating/connecting the db:",e.args[0]
        exit(1)

    return conn

def write_db(conn,cursor,fni):
    conn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS file (filenames TEXT UNIQUE)")
    query = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO file VALUES($filenames)"

    cursor.execute(query,[fni])
    cursor.close()  
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print fni,"should now be in the db" 
    exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(argv) == 2:
        etag = argv[1]
    else:
        print "no argument given - stopping now"
        exit(1)

    conn = define_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    write_db(conn,cursor,fni)
```

I keep getting this error and was not able to solve it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blah.py", line 37, in <module>
    write_db(conn,cursor,fni)
NameError: name 'fni' is not defined
```

Any idea what the problem is.

At this moment I use python 2.7.3

Comment: The error is printed right there! `name 'fni' is not defined` So check to make sure `fni` has a value

Comment: True, I try to pass it like this via the command line.

`python blah.py helloworld`

Or is there something completely I am missing out

Comment: From the looks of it, you are putting the argument into `etag`

Comment: @TheZ: How did I miss that. Dumb! Thanks a ton!

Comment: No worries, always double check your assumptions :)

Answer (score 2):

The last line of your script refers to a name `fni` that is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the variable "fni", but you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Static analysis tools like `pyflakes` or `pylint` can be useful to catch silly errors like this

If you wrote the bulk of the code in a function (so it doesn't assume `blub` is a global variable, which don't make pyflakes/pylint complain):

```
def main():
    if len(argv) == 2:
        blub = argv[1]
    else:
        print "no argument given - stopping now"
        exit(1)

    conn = define_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    write_db(conn,cursor,fni)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

...then you would get a pair of errors, which points out exactly what the error is (you stored the argument in `blub`, but tried to access it with `fni`):

```
$ pip install pyflakes
$ pyflakes example.py
example.py:30: local variable 'blub' is assigned to but never used
example.py:37: undefined name 'fni'
```